# Truffle serve not finding css and javascript files

Tags: solidity, truffle

the directory is getting served wrong in truffle and I can't figure out where to change it....

The terminal response is...

```
Couldn't find file at .//app/app.js.
```

My build file.......

```
module.exports = {
          build: {
            "index.html": "index.html",
            "app.js": [
              "javascripts/app.js"
            ],
            "app.css": [
              "css/app.css"
            ],
            "images/": "images/"
          },
          rpc: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 8545
          }
        };
```

My index.html file .......

```
    <link href="./css/app.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="./javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app.css is a bundle which contains "css/app.css"  and could contain many other css files. The bundle app.css is a concat of each file. 
That way your bundle app.css is available at the root level **href=". /app.css"**
Same thing for app.js

Comment: Great thanks! If I want to add other css files can I add it to the app.css list........ "app.css": [
      "css/app.css" , "css/othercssfile.css"
    ],

Comment: Exactly, put all your css files in the array [] and they will be merged by truffle into a unique file app.css before nodejs starts.